# Wildcard searching for custom field queries

Tags: search, query, wildcard

I've noticed that the * wildcard works for simple custom field queries, for example if I have three entries named `Foo`, `Foo*`, `Foo*Bar`, running

`craft.entries.title('Foo*').all()`

will get 3 results, and if I dump the raw SQL there's a LIKE% statement. Is there a way to disable this behavior and query for an exact match? I could filter the results  with `firstWhere()` or similar, but it seems like an unexpected behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out asterisks can be escaped with a double slash, so you can query

```
craft.entries.title('Foo\\*').all()
```

and it will match `Foo*`